# Which Adobe tools are most appropriate to make App Store icons, and images?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, icon, mobile, dreamweaver

I am a programmer and need to put something on the App Store in test mode (TestFlight, HockeyApp, etc).

I need to create a variety of images, logos, and other material for the submission... but I have no design skill.

What tooling (or skills) will get me to my goal the fastest?  If the answer is Dreamweaver or Illustrator, is there anything I should focus on, or explicitly avoid?

Answer (score 4):

**It's not about the tools**

I have some bad news for you I'm afraid. The tools won't help you.

You can dismiss Dreamweaver immediately since that isn't a design tool (in any reasonable sense of the word) it's a code editor.

That leaves you with two industry standard design packages, Photoshop and Illustrator. Either of these could be used to create logos (etc) but Photoshop is more suited to raster artwork, and illustrator to vector. [More about raster and vector](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/68643/what-does-the-term-raster-and-vector-apply-to/68646#68646).

**Hire a professional**

I am being entirely non-sarcastic when I urge you to find a professional designer to carry out the work, seeing as you yourself have declared you have no design skill.

The takeaway here is that no software can possibly make up for a lack of design skills.